# Still points in a rigid body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm reading [Woodhouse's](https://www.amazon.it/Introduction-Analytical-Dynamics-N-Woodhouse/dp/1848828152) book on classical mechanics and I got stuck on this problem:

> A rigid body has angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$ and has one point $O$ ﬁxed relative to a frame $\tilde{R}$. Show that if $\vec{\omega} \times \tilde{D}\vec{\omega} \neq 0$, then $O$ is the only point with zero acceleration relative to $\tilde{R}$.

*Note.* $\tilde{D}\vec{\omega}$ is the derivative with respect to time of $\vec{\omega}$ in $\tilde{R}$.

*My approach.* Suppose there exists $P$ in the rigid body with null acceleration and let $\vec{r}$ be the vector going from $O$ to $P$. Since the body is rigid, we have that the velocity $\vec{v}_P$ with respect to $\tilde{R}$ satisfies $$\vec{v}_P = \vec{v}_O + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$$ 
On differentiation with respect to time we get $$0 = \tilde{D}\vec{v}_P = \tilde{D}(\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}) = (\tilde{D}\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}) + (\vec{\omega} \times \tilde{D}\vec{r}) = (\tilde{D}\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}) + (\vec{\omega} \times \vec{v}_P)$$
From this point on every manipulation I tried to prove that $\vec{r}$ must be the zero vector got me nowhere.

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is stream of conciousness attempt:

Take the scalar product of your expression with with $\omega$ to get
$$
0 = \omega\cdot (\dot \omega\times r)+ \omega\cdot (\omega\times v_P)
$$
The last term is zero and 
$$
0=\omega\cdot (\dot \omega\times r)= r\cdot (\omega\times \dot \omega)
$$
So $r$ has no component parallel to $(\omega\times \dot \omega)$ and  $r$ must lie in the plane defined by $\omega$ and $\dot \omega$.

Note added: actually we dont need the above. Start below:

From 
$$
0 =  (\dot \omega\times r)+ (\omega\times v)
$$ 
and 
$$
(\omega\times v)=\omega \times(\omega\times r)= (\omega\cdot r)\omega- r |\omega|^2
$$ we see firtly that that $\dot \omega \times r$  is perpendicular to $r$ so taking the scalar product we get
$$
0=(\omega\cdot r)^2-|r|^2||\omega|^2
$$ so $r$ is parallel to 
$\omega$ --- i.e  $r=a\omega$ and this  makes $v=(\omega\times r)=0$.
 Once we have  $v=0$ then we have
$$
0=(\dot \omega\times r)= a(\dot \omega\times \omega)
$$
Thus $a$ is zero. Hence (because $\omega\ne 0$)  $r$ is zero